# How to maintain previous data and current data in react usestate in react-native or reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

Currently i am learning reactjs. I want to store my previous data and upcoming data in usestate . IS there any trick for that ?

**For example :**
Firstly i input "A" after that i input "B". I want A and B are stored in usestate even when i add new data in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy. You can use my code snippet. With the help of this you can store your previous data and upcoming data as well.

**Method 1:**

```
const [arrayOfObjs, handleObjSelection] = useState([]);
// on a buttton for example
<button
  onClick={selectedObj => handleObjSelection(
              prevSelected => [...prevSelected, selectedObj],
          ))}
>
```

**Method 2:**

```
const [ store, setStore] = useState([]);
 .....

 setStore(...store, upcomingData);
```

Here Upcoming Data is the data which you want to  add in the useState. It can be store as well. Like:

```
const [ store, setStore] = useState([]);
     .....
    
     setStore(...store, store);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use object state for this then you can keep both state. Here is the working version https://codesandbox.io/embed/frosty-bird-hg3izs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState({previous: '', current: ''})

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setObj({previous: obj.current, current: e.target.value})
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={obj.current} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
      <p>I am previous {obj.previous} </p>
      <p>I am current {obj.current} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey !! I found above one more convenient. Also your code is useful but it creates objects but i want in array form. Thanks for sharing !!

Comment: In my answer I store just two values but in other answer it has no limit, it keeps each values as long as you change state instead of keeping just necessary two values. You are welcome @Taehyung

Comment: Yes !! i want all the previous values